# What is ICANN domain status: 'clientTransferProhibited'?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, icann

I checked the `Domain Status` of some domains (using [ICANN](https://lookup.icann.org/lookup) and one was `Active`, whereas the other was `clientTransferProhibited`.

i.e.

> Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited

and

> Domain Status: Active

What are the practical effects of setting the domain status to `clientTransferProhibited`, and is it the recommended approach for a serious website, or is 'Active' domain status considered safe?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [How to know if a domain is locked or not?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26462/how-to-know-if-a-domain-is-locked-or-not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is offtopic here but any conforming whois server (or if using RDAP) shows things that way:

```
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited
```

Note the hyperlinks given.

And for your specific one, the text displayed after the jump is:

> This status indicates that it is not possible to transfer the domain name registration, which will help prevent unauthorized transfers resulting from hijacking and/or fraud. If you do want to transfer your domain, you must first contact your registrar and request that they remove this status code.

To nitpick, note that this is not "ICANN" status. The name comes from EPP, which is a protocol used by all gTLD registries and most of ccTLDs (but not all).

> and is it the recommended approach for a serious website

This is vague in your question, but if you are serious about your domain name you should have a look at the following services that may be available for your domain (depending on who the registrar and the registry are):

- "registrar lock" (or any other equivalent marketing name): this means your domain could not (more precisely: more difficult) be hijacked because it has an extra layer of protection that typically requires phoning the registrar or separate passwords, etc. When activated you may see `clientUpdateProhibited` and `clientDeleteProhibited` statuses typically. And `clientTransferProhibited` also (but this is often set by many registrars anyway, even outside this service, just to protect domains against hijacked transfers)
- "registry lock": this is kind of the same logic but one step further. Even if the EPP connection from registrar to registry is hijacked, your domain could not be modified without some extra loops of authentication out of band, between the registry and registrar. In cases like that you may see `serverUpdateProhibited` or `serverDeleteProhibited`.

Side note: all statuses starting with `client` are set by the registrar (and it has full power on adding/removing them) and all with `server` at start, as well as any other, can only be set/removed by the registry and hence outside of registrar control. Registries do use them also during disputes for examples and things like that.

Note that the two services described above are not free, not standardized across registries or registrars (so what they cover exactly and what statuses they set or not will vary), and seldom used. But they are a real added protection.